# how to change save button to Save and keep published?

Tags: 8, nodes

In the content form want to change the  publish checkbox and save button into the dropdown "**Save and keep published**" and **Save and unpublish**
How can i change the layout for all content type.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you want to change the node edit form back to the old layout of Drupal 8.3. You can use this module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/publishing_dropbutton

Comment: its work for me how can i hide the checkbox publish . it's not hiding it

Comment: see the module page: Navigate to the node "manage form display" tab, move the 'status' field into the "hidden" region

Comment: i checked the content type there is no field publish to hidden under the manage display

Comment: This is the wrong tab, use "Manage form display" and move the field "Published" into the disabled section.